# How to increase weight of a word for CountVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a document that I tokenized, and then I take another document and I compare the two by calculating their *cosine similarity*.

However, before I calculate their similarity, I want to increase the weight of one of the words beforehand. I'm thinking of doing this by doubling the count of that word, but I do not know how to do that.

Suppose I have the following...

```
text = [
    "This is a test",
    "This is something else",
    "This is also a test"
]

test = ["This is something"]
```

Next I define the stop words and call `CountVectorizer` for both sets of documents.

```
stopWords = set(stopwords.words('english'))

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopWords)

trainVectorizerArray = vectorizer.fit_transform(text).toarray()
testVectorizerArray = vectorizer.transform(test).toarray()
```

In the next part I calculate the *cosine similarity*...

```
cosine_function = lambda a, b : round(np.inner(a, b)/(LA.norm(a)*LA.norm(b)), 3)

for vector in trainVectorizerArray:
    print(vector)
    for testV in testVectorizerArray:
        print(testV)
        cosine = cosine_function(vector, testV)
        print(cosine)
```

However, before I calculate the similarity, how can I increase the weight of one of the words. Suppose in this example I want to increase the weight of `something`, how can I do that? I think you do this by increasing the word count but I do not know how to increase that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use the `get_feature_names` function for your `CountVectorizer` in combination with the `cosine` function in `scipy.spatial.distance`. But be aware that this computes cosine distance rather than similarity, so if you are just interested in similarity you must use `similarity = 1-distance`. Using your example

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
import numpy as np

word_weights = {'something': 2}
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
weights = np.ones(len(feature_names))

for key, value in word_weights.items():
    weights[feature_names.index(key)] = value

for vector in trainVectorizerArray:
    print(vector)
    for testV in testVectorizerArray:
        print(testV)
        cosine_unweight = cosine(vector, testV)
        cosine_weighted = cosine(vector, testV, w=weights)
        print(cosine_unweight, cosine_weighted)
```

As requested a bit more of an explanation for the `word_weights` dictionary. It's the weight that you're assigning to the other words. Each of weights is set to `1` unless you add an entry into the `word_weights` dictionary, so `word_weights = {'test': 0}` would remove the "test" from the cosine similarity, but `word_weights = {'test': 1.5}` would increase the weighting by 50% compared to other words. You can also include multiple entries if you need too, for example `word_weights = {'test': 1.5, 'something': 2}` will adjust the weighting of both "test" and "something" compared to the other words.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the `2` represents in `{'something': 2}`?

Comment: Edited my answer to include it.